# Why Collections name always comes plural?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am learning about MongoDB...My Collection is always coming plural naming...

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("a", UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("name", UserSchema);
```

My mongo DB collection name always comes in

```
users
as
names
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Since a collection doesn't have one user or one name.